# Pass non const char * in to const char *& argument of a function

Tags: c++, reference

I want to pass strings to a function but save the cost of
copying the pointer on the function's stack to improve performance.
I am aware of the multithreading hazards of manipulating const-ness.

One thing is to use `&arr[idx]` (char array) as a pointer to pass to
`void func( const char*& charArrItemRef)`.

Compiler complains it can't bind the reference to function arg.
how can I manipulate the build to allow it?

Comment: Your question would be helped immeasurably by adding a concrete code example.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your `func` is expecting a reference to a `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to first forcefully cast a `char*` to `const char*`, store it in a variable and then pass that variable to your `func`. Note that it has to be stored in a variable since you are passing the pointer as a reference. Hope this is what you were looking for:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(const char* &charArrItemRef)
{
    cout << charArrItemRef << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char* a[5] = {(char*)"abc", (char*)"def", (char*)"sss", (char*)"dasds", (char*)"aad"};
    const char* c = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(a[0]);
    func(c);

    // EDIT:
    char b[10] = "abcdefghi";
    const char* d = &b[3];
    func(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no, the purpose of the function is to act on a single string, so it is mandatory to take reference from middle of char* string. for example car a[] = "abcdefghi";

now take the 4th position as const ref pointer using (const char *&)&a[3]r
insert as argument to a function
void function(const char*& refToPointerInternalInArray)

Comment: You cannot pass `rvalue` by reference - it will throw compile time error. For the behavior you want, please see my updated answer (in the code).